# Reusing Fetch with Different Pieces of State in React (Flux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have this function that is in the top level component that I'd like to reuse but on a different piece of state. In the following code sample, I'm using it on userData, but I'd like to be able to reuse it on a piece of state called repoData, either within the same component it's child, or outside. Just not sure how to go about it, since, if I do something like pass it the states as args, setting the state would throw an error because it would look like: this.setState({this.state.userData: data}).

```
    fetchUserData(params) {
        fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + params)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error("Network failure")
          }
        return response;
        })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          userData: data
        })
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
            requestFailed: true
        })
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more about refactoring your code I believe. Here you can look at it as moving out the logic of fetching user data asynchronously. Your component need not know who(`fetch`, `axios`) is doing the work of fetching the data for it. Also it is not required for a component to know from where(`https://api.github.com/users/' + params`) to get this data.
One possible way of doing it is to move your fetch call in a separate function which will return the data to your component after fetching it asynchronously. Then it is responsibility of component to handle the data the way it want to.
So as you can see the key point here is identifying and separating out the responsibilities of each piece of code. Advantages of doing this will be clean code structure, less number of lines, maintainable code and most importantly easily testable code.
I hope this solves your problem. If you are interested to learn about such techniques more you can read about **DRY principle** and **refactoring techniques**.

**Edit 1:**
I have created this code sample for your reference 
[image: Edit j2nj1r76k3]

What are JavaScript Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
Some samples for fetch: https://davidwalsh.name/fetch
I personally recommend using axios. You can see comparison of fetch and axios here: https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/fetch-vs-axios-js-for-making-http-requests-2b261cdd3af5

Comment: That all makes sense but I'm new to fetch and API's and can't see what fetch is returning. Would I set the result to a variable or something? Like let userData = fetchUserData(params) and then set my state to userData?

Comment: @JessieRichardson Yes I guess you are going in right direction. For structuring your code, please take a look at the code in the answer I have provided here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963781/react-testing-onsubmit-using-axios/48213958#48213958). If it helps you let me know or else I will try to elaborate my answer.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure I follow. I'll take another look in the morning. Thanks though!

Comment: Still need help with this.

Comment: @JessieRichardson I have modified my answer and added a code sample, take a look

Comment: @JessieRichardson Was that of any help to you?

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. I had figured out how to at least get the response by returning the whole fetch but that was not helping resolve error messages. Cheers!

Comment: Although the only issue is that the error is not displaying to the console when I enter an invalid user. It works in your code, but not in mine when I write the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly

- you should move the function to a file `x.js`
- it should accept an other param which is the name of the new (piece) of state
- it should also accept a param for the `this.setState` of the component calling it.
- import it and use it in `componentDidMount` as normal

```

```
export const fetchUserData(params,setState , stateParam) {
     fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + params)
        .then(response => {
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error("Network failure")
          }
        return response;
        })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        setState({
          [stateParam]: data
        })
      }, () => {
        setState({
            requestFailed: true
        })
      })
  }
```

you can call it as follows

```
import { fetchUserDate } from "./path/to/x"

fetchUserDate("param" , this.setState, "xOnState")
```

Comment: I do need to use something like this but the code you posted is not working for me. Seems like passing this.setState is where the problem lies. I keep getting error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'updater' of undefined"