# How Do I Set State with External Function in React (And Should I?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have an API fetch request that I'd like to use in 2 different places on 2 different sets of data.

I tried to implement the answer from user, aeid, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220755/reusing-fetch-with-different-pieces-of-state-in-react-flux/48220999?noredirect=1#comment83470450_48220999) but it is not working. I know that I can successfully update the state if I nest the fetch request within my components, but I don't want to do that since I need to reuse this code and that would not be very DRY.

My API fetch in `api.js` is:

```
export const getGithub = (url, setState, userData) => {
        return fetch(root_url + url)
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    connectionFailure();
                }
                return res;
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => setState({
                [userData]: data
            }))
}
```

And I am calling it in my components like this:

```
 componentWillMount() {
      getGithub(this.state.username, this.setState, "userData")

}
```

Have tried variations such as removing the brackets from `userData`, and passing it as `this.state.userData` instead of a string, but to no success.

Comment: You could probably work around the issue to do it like this, but it wouldn't be idiomatic. You'd be better off removing the last `then` from your `getGithub` function and making the call to setState in your component.

Comment: `userData` is a variable. you can name it whatever you like, for example `getGithub = (url, setState, myKey) => {` and pass it whatever string you want

Comment: That's how I had it before, but what about updating the state when I get an error? Need to be able to update state for that as well.

Comment: The same thing applies, you can chain a `catch` from the promise returned by `getGithub`.

Comment: I was under the impression that catch does not work with fetch since the response is only ok or not ok. I have seen some examples of people using it but not sure how it's working if that's the case.

Comment: It will if you either throw an exception or return a rejected promise.